# How to display errors on a custom theme wordpress white screen of death?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wsod

Such a generic problem would obviously have numerous solutions on the Web, right?

My company uses a custom purchased wordpress template, which worked fine till yesterday, for unknown reasons.

I am perfectly assured this is a template related WSOD, which is problematic, because they still wish to use the same template.

I'd be glad to finally solve the problem, but without error output it is only a wild guess what had happened.

How to hit the nail of the head without the following:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

or reading the error_log in the root of a host? Because both failed to show anything, with latter being empty.

What are the other commands to force WP to show the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of your server will be preventing the errors from being shown even with WP_DEBUG on.

Try this in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

This will log the errors to a file inside wp-content titled debug.log.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging

Comment: Thank you very much! it turned out to be suddenly undefined variable in a custom php script of the template. But now that's my task to solve it... \